# Error during boost and dlib installation for Python 3.6

Tags: python, c++, boost, build, dlib

I am struggling to install dlib for Python 3.6 on Windows 10. I've installed and built boost, added ...\boost_1_63_0 folder along with ...\boost_1_63_0\stage\lib folder to the `PATH`. 
But I still have the following message

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'python36.lib' [C:\Users\admin\dlib\tools\python\build\dlib_.vcxproj]
    19 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:05:03.17
error: cmake build failed!
```

when I try to type `python setup.py install` in command prompt.

Also, I have `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_python-vc140-mt-s-1_63.lib'` message, when I try to install dlib through `pip install dlib`.

Please, help me! Otherwise, I'm feeling desperate right now after all those hours of searching for a valid solution.

Comment: You need to add a lib path to your python libs. `C:\..\Python36_3\libs`. That is where the `python36.lib` lives. Also, you need to add your `c:\..\Python36_3\include` to your includes or boost will not know you are linking with python3.

Answer (score 1):

After all those wasted hours of search, I have finally fixed this problem. So I will just leave the way that worked for me, so people who will face the same problem in future could find it.

The reason for such an error was that dlib's latest version doesn't support Python 3.6, which I have never noticed anywhere except [this page](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dlib).

The solution for problem was to install Python 3.5 and to add `C:\..\Python35\libs`, `C:\..\Python35\include`, `C:\..\Python35`, `C:\..\Python35\Scripts` paths to Windows system `PATH`.